# Do happy people live more sustainably?

Tags: lifestyle

I am wondering if there is any evidence that happy people (i.e. generally satisfied with their life condition) live more sustainable (i.e. have a lower environmental footprint) than unhappy people.

Comment: What is your motivation for asking this question? What relationship do you imagine connects happiness to environmental footprint?

Comment: My assumption would be that people who have an inner satisfaction are less materialistic and thus consume less energy and materials.

Comment: why would one be the consequence of the other and not the other way round? Also, which culture are you referring to?

Comment: Good point. This is opening an entire field of new questions. I will start to research this deeper. Thank you for the thoughts.

Comment: The less satisfaction I have at work, the more I feel like forgetting environmental issues and buying stuff, expensive holidays, long flights away from "here". I am very curious about this.

Comment: The question should not be closed as 'opinion-based' because it very clearly asks about **evidence**. Maybe it cannot be answered yet, maybe it needs some edits to make it sharper, so at most it would be 'too broad'.

Answer (score 2):

The largest predictor of sustainable consumption is poverty. The diverse rich all consume far more resources. Because there is a robust relationship between income and health, and even between income and happiness, I would expect that across large populations the happiest are behaving less sustainably.

> The environmental behavior of rich countries affects poor countries much more than the reverse, even given the much lower population of rich countries:
> https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/3322505/Environment-damage-of-rich-countries-on-poor.html
>
> Happiness increases linearly with income, and then plateaus
> https://qz.com/1211957/how-much-money-do-people-need-to-be-happy/

Comment: Welcome to Sustainability.SE, and thanks for your answer! Could you provide a few key details from the links you've added, so that it will still be helpful in the event that the links break?